# Mountain Lion error when installing ruby, libbz2.1.0.dylib wrong architecture

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-mountain-lion

I updated my mac to mountain lion. Now when i try to install ruby `rvm install 1.9.3` i am getting this error

```
linking shared-object tcltklib.bundle
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64) for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../../.ext/x86_64-darwin12.0.0/tcltklib.bundle] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/tk/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

How I cane update libbz2 to correct architecture?

Answer (score -1):

Update Xcode (to 4.4).  
Once done, install Command Line Tools from Xcode => Preferences => Downloads => Command Line Tools.  Then try installing ruby and you'll be good.

Comment: i've already done this. it doesn't help. what is this file libbz2.1.0.dylib? i think it is compiled for 32 and not for 64.

Comment: yep it does, it's one of the binaries used for ImageMagick

Comment: i suppose you've ImageMagick installed as well which would require a new installation post Mountain Lion upgrade.  I wrote a small [how-to](http://rb512.blogspot.com/2012/07/fix-to-get-rmagick-working-after.html) to fix it:

Comment: thanks, this is what i've done:

`brew uninstall imagemagick;
rm /usr/local/lib/libbz2.1.dylib;
rm /usr/local/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib;
brew install imagemagick;`

Comment: Argh! Why do so many Mac Ruby development problems end up in "update XCode"??